How to change the background color of LottieAnimationView in Android
I have used a LottieAnimationView in my andriod XML with a lottie animation file. The animation file itself has transparent background but the LottieAnimationView has a white background that I can't seem to change.
When I go to dark mode, the LottieAnimationView's white background is visible.

I tried changing the background tag in XML but non of it works. Here the the XML:
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                    android:id="@+id/anim_start_btn"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_110sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:background="@color/background"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/background"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:lottie_speed="1.2"
                    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/start_btn"
                    app:lottie_autoPlay="false"
                    app:lottie_loop="false"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_start_instruction"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    />


What version of Lottie are you using?

6.4.1 the latest one

I suspected that's due to the bug fixed in v6.2.0 but then that's not the case. https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/pull/2377

According to the contributor of the lottie-android, "Lottie has no notion of a background".
As the comment was about two years ago I'm not sure if it's still valid but it would be better for you to double-check whether your animation doesn't really have a white background and the parent view in XML doesn't have a white background.

Yep the parent view does not have a white background but for lottie animation, I'll just double check it. Once anything is confirmed, I'll update here.
